# plural form of element using page-object gem

Tags: ruby, selenium, page-object-gem

I need to identify number of rows inside a table, but I get (NoMethodError) all the time.

Here is row element:

```
row :purchases_table_row, css: ".purchases tbody tr
```

When I call:

```
puts on(DashboardPage).purchases_table_row_element
```

I get a good answer, element is there:

```
#<PageObject::Elements::TableRow:0x007fd92b8420e0>
```

When I call

```
puts on(DashboardPage).purchases_table_row_elements
```

I got this:

```
undefined method `purchases_table_row_elements' for #
<DashboardPage:0x007fcd03d301f8>
      Did you mean?  purchases_table_row_element
                     purchases_table_element (NoMethodError)
```

I'm using selenium webdriver (tried with watir with no luck), page-object. According to this link https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/defining-element-collections-using-the-page-objects-gem/

define purchases_table_row_element**s** should do the trick.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The method `purchases_table_row_elements` is only defined when you use the plural form of the accessor. In other words `row` needs to be `rows`:

```
# Plural
rows :purchases_table_row, css: ".purchases tbody tr"
#=> defines page.purchases_table_row_elements

# Singular
row :purchases_table_row, css: ".purchases tbody tr"
#=> defines page.purchases_table_row_element
```

Comment: That was easy. Thank you.